# C++ Outputting a map

Tags: c++, maps

What is the easiest way to output a map?

```
map < int , string > BIG_MAP;
```

The method I use for insertion is:

```
BIG_MAP[x] = y;
```

I can't find any way which works.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by output? Do you mean to create a map, to pass a map from a function, or to print a map?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a way to print a map. All you need to do is to iterate over all its elements and print them one by one. Now that question comes how do you iterate over the elements? For that you can either use an iterator `BIG_MAP.begin()` and increment it till you reach `BIG_MAP.end()`. You can also use the range based for loop shown below.

```
for (auto x: map)
  cout << x.first << " " << x.second << endl;
```